# Can someone explain the Recursion in this Code

Tags: java

I've done HTML but that is nothing like learning java now in my AP class. So I'm pretty much brand new to coding. Today we learned about recursion and I'm pretty sure I understood it when it comes to using it like in this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpuWkZs51aM

But we then had to use it in a different way. We needed to make a program called WordPlay that accept any words, one at a time, until the word "STOP" is input. When stop was put in it prints them back out in reverse order. Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter list of words, one per line");
        System.out.println("Final word should be STOP");
        wordList();
    }
    public static void wordList()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String word = keyboard.next();
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"))
            System.out.println();
        else
            wordList();
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

So the part that I don't understand is that this works fine but when I look at the ending of `wordList()` it seems to me that it would just keep repeating the last word that was input. I don't get what I'm missing. Can someone explain the logic here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion *does* output the word that was input, however each call to `wordList` gets a new *local* variable named `word` (each `word` value is on "[the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)"). If you mark it `final`, nothing will complain - because the `word` isn't modified after *initialization*. Also, you should probably extract the `Scanner` (each invocation creates a new local one of those too).

```
public static void wordList()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    final String word = keyboard.next(); // <-- this is the current word.
    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) 
        System.out.println();
    else
        wordList(); // <-- it's not STOP, recurse... which 
                    //     will get a new local word (and print it).
    System.out.println(word); // <-- however, this is still current word.
}
```

Comment: Ok. So if I'm understanding this right then when it gets STOP" it auto prints it leaving "word" = to the previous string. Then when that string is printed it sets "word" = to the string before that and so on until it prints all values?

That''s the part I don't understand. Once it prints out STOP and the last String that "word" had what makes the rest of the stack print?

Comment: @JustABitSalty It prints the value of `word`, it's important to note that `new String("a") != new String("a")` and in that sense the value of `word` never changed. Each invocation has its' own *local* variables.

Comment: Ok. I get it now with yours and the other post explain the sequence of operations. As for moving the scanner somewhere else. Would that cause a memory issue in an actual program? I remember our teacher telling us the stack is stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The function will execute from top to bottom as usual, but if it enters the else block it will jump back up to the beginning like shown below. It will 'loop' exactly like this until `word` equals "STOP", then it'll enter the if block, print out a new line (`System.out.println()`) then SKIP the else block, print out `word` then exit the function. Brackets in the if-else statement will make this easier to see.

```
public static void wordList()
{
  |->Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  |
  | String word = keyboard.next();
  | if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) {
  |   System.out.println();
  | }
  | else {
  |---wordList();
    }
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its basically a recursion function or method which calls itself again and again until if condition inside it is false.
So here first new word entered by user is stored in variable called `word`, then `if condition` will check if value stored in `word` is `Stop`, if its not then again `wordlist` method is called and all above process is repeated again. 
So each time new values entered is stored in `word` variable.
Thats all!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int wordList()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word = keyboard.next();
    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"))
    {
      System.out.println();
      return 0;
    }
    System.out.println(word);
    return wordList();
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

This will be the sequence of operations

1) call wordlist() 
2) Get a word, say WORD1 and store in local variable word. 
3) before calling wordlist recursively, WORD1 goes into stack. Stack is something like a box where you can fill say biscuits one over an other, and you can take out the biscuit that you placed last. Now the stack has WORD1 
4) get another word, say WORD2 and store in local variable word. This is a new function call, even if it is recursive. So a new local variable word is allocated memory. 
5) before calling wordlist recursively, WORD2 goes into stack. So now WORD2 will be the top one and WORD1 will be below in the stack. 
5) get another work, now it is STOP. 
6) STOP is printed 
7) function returns
8) now the flow returns to previous call. Now WORD2 is popped out of stack as the local variable holding WORD2 belongs to this instance of the recursive call. 
8) print WORD2 and return to previous call. Now WORD1 is popped out of the stack as the local variable holding WORD1 belongs to this instance of the recursive call 
9) WORD1 printed.

Just to tell you an analogy, let us assume you have a similar task. You have to get a set of books from a friend standing besides you. You have to give him back the books in the reverse order as you got it from him as soon as he gives you a book named stop.

1) You get the book from him  
2) before getting the next book, you keep it on a table, since you cannot hold this and get more books from your friend 
3) yet get the next book from him  
4) before getting the next book, you keep it over the first book  
5) you continue doing this until you get a book named stop  
6) now you start returning the books, first you will return the book named stop and as you continue, since the books are stacked, you will be returning the book in reverse order.

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

It would just repeat that last word entered if the line `System.out.println(word)` was before the `if` statement.

To understand recursion, you need the notion of the "stack".  Each call to `wordList()` occurs in a separate level in the stack.  There is a different `word` variable in each of these stack levels.

Since the ``System.out.println(word)` line happen after the recursive call, each of these are executed when un-piling the stack (i.e. after the previous level returns).  That's why words appear in reverse order.  Image: if you pile boxes one atop the other, when you un-pile them, the last box is the first to go out (hence the acronym LIFO=Last In First Out).

Another important concept for recursion is to have a way of stopping it (i.e. prevent infinite recursion).  In this program, it is done when the user enters "STOP".

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of these problems as a 'call stack'. Each time you 'call' the method recursively you add another 'stack'. Every recursive method needs a stopping case. In your problem the first occurrence of the word 'STOP' (how convenient) acts as your stopping case. 
For example if someone enters:

"Fox"
"Bear"
"Deer"
"STOP"

As soon as the word "STOP" appears, it will be printed. Now we pick up where we left off in your 'call stack' which is the ending of

wordList()

Now the only step left is

System.out.println(word)

The word 'Deer' will be printed and now our list being printed is:

"STOP"
"Deer"

And so forth until we reach the last word.